# CSS: Pause animation on timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I am implementing a time counter.

The objective is that user can start the timer, and when he feels like it, he can pause or continue the timer.

The difficulty I encountered was pausing the SVG animation.

I followed this [article](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-play-and-pause-css-animations-with-css-custom-properties/), however it does not work.

Any suggestions?

### CODE

```js
(function() {
    const start = document.querySelector( '.start' ),
      togglePause = document.querySelector( '.pause' ),
        seconds = 60;

    function format( seconds ) {
        var sec = Math.floor( seconds % 60 ),
            min = Math.floor( seconds / 60 );

            secdisp = sec;
            mindisp = min;

            if( min === 0 && sec === 0 ) {
                clearInterval( countdown );
            } else if ( secdisp === 0 ) {
                min--;
                sec = 0;
            }
    
          return mindisp + ':' + ( secdisp < 10 ? '0' + secdisp : secdisp );
    }

    function tickdown( seconds ) {
        var mod = Math.floor( seconds % 60 ),
            min = Math.floor( seconds / 60 ) - ( mod === 0 ? 1 : 0 ),
            sec = ( mod ? 60 - mod : 0 );

        var tick = () => {
            seconds--;
    
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = format( seconds );
        };
        tick();
        countdown = setInterval( tick, 1000 );
    }

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = format( seconds );

    start.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var gauge = document.querySelector( '.timer-gauge' ),
            frame = document.querySelector( 'html' );


        tickdown( seconds );
        gauge.style.transitionDuration = seconds + 's';
        gauge.classList.add('ticking');
    });
  
  togglePause.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    var gauge = document.querySelector( '.timer-gauge' );
    const running = gauge.style.animationPlayState === 'running';
     gauge.style.animationPlayState = running ? 'paused' : 'running';  
    
  });
}());
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #5967c3 0%,#76b8d6 100%);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;

}

html:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;

}
html.started:after {
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #52b670 0%,#84c86d 100%);
    opacity: 1;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
.main {
    max-width: 100%;

}
.chart-gauge {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: central;
    alignment-baseline: middle;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
.timer-time {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
.timer-backdrop {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    stroke-width: 5;
}
.timer-gauge {
    transform: rotate(-270deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    stroke-width: 5;
    animation: fill 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.ticking {
    stroke-dashoffset: 360;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes fill {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 360; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" class="chart-gauge" fill="none" stroke-width="2">
    <circle class="timer-backdrop" stroke-dasharray="360" r="57.32" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
    <circle class="timer-gauge" stroke-dasharray="360" r="57.32" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
    <text y="50%" x="50%" id="time" class="timer-time">1:00</text>
  </svg>

  <button class="start">Start</button>
</div>
<button class="pause">Toggle Pause</button>
```

## CODE

Code change with the suggestion of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127151/8098173).

The problem now is that the animation got faster in the middle and slower at the beginning and at the end, so it will not hit the right spots on the "clock"

```js
(function() {
    const start = document.querySelector( '.start' ),
      togglePause = document.querySelector( '.pause' ),
        seconds = 60;

    function format( seconds ) {
        var sec = Math.floor( seconds % 60 ),
            min = Math.floor( seconds / 60 );

            secdisp = sec;
            mindisp = min;

            if( min === 0 && sec === 0 ) {
                clearInterval( countdown );
            } else if ( secdisp === 0 ) {
                min--;
                sec = 0;
            }
    
          return mindisp + ':' + ( secdisp < 10 ? '0' + secdisp : secdisp );
    }

    function tickdown( seconds ) {
        var mod = Math.floor( seconds % 60 ),
            min = Math.floor( seconds / 60 ) - ( mod === 0 ? 1 : 0 ),
            sec = ( mod ? 60 - mod : 0 );

        var tick = () => {
            seconds--;
    
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = format( seconds );
        };
        tick();
        countdown = setInterval( tick, 1000 );
    }

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = format( seconds );

    start.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var gauge = document.querySelector( '.timer-gauge' ),
            frame = document.querySelector( 'html' );


        tickdown( seconds );
        gauge.style.animationDuration = seconds + 's';
        gauge.classList.add('ticking');
    });
  
  togglePause.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    var gauge = document.querySelector( '.timer-gauge' );
    const running = gauge.style.animationPlayState === 'running';
     gauge.style.animationPlayState = running ? 'paused' : 'running';  
    
  });
}());
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #5967c3 0%,#76b8d6 100%);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;

}

html:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .1s linear;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;

}
html.started:after {
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #52b670 0%,#84c86d 100%);
    opacity: 1;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
.main {
    max-width: 100%;

}
.chart-gauge {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: central;
    alignment-baseline: middle;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
.timer-time {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
.timer-backdrop {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    stroke-width: 5;
}
.timer-gauge {
    transform: rotate(-270deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    fill: none;
    stroke: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    stroke-width: 5;
    animation-name: initial-fill;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
.ticking {
animation-name: fill;
    stroke-dashoffset: 360;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes initial-fill {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 360; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

@keyframes fill {
  0%   { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 360; }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">  
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" class="chart-gauge" fill="none" stroke-width="2">
            <circle class="timer-backdrop" stroke-dasharray="360" r="57.32" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
            <circle class="timer-gauge" stroke-dasharray="360" r="57.32" cx="60" cy="60"></circle>
            <text y="50%" x="50%" id="time" class="timer-time">1:00</text>
        </svg>

        <button class="start">Start</button>
</div>

        <button class="pause">Toggle Pause</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it; just digging up old knowledge.

With `animation: fill 1s;` **shorthand** notation
you are also messing with the `animation-play-state` setting.

Try using all separate properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

and a `animation-play-state: running` (or paused) to start with

#### Update

If I change your CSS to:

```
    xanimation: fill 1s;
    animation-name: fill;
    animation-duration:60s;
    animation-play-state:paused;
```

Your toggle does ***something***

So play-state toggle works

Now you have to make your CSS and SVG do what you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do what you said, but it didn't work :/

Comment: See update, I could not copy your code into the answer with one click anymore

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and it didn't work :/  I have this codepen, if you want to see it - https://codepen.io/saomartinho/pen/oNYrbRe

Comment: So apply the change I made and take it from there. You are mixing ``animation`` and ``transition`` and using the fill animation for your first "init" **and** countdown.. take it apart

Comment: Okay, it worked, ty. But now another problem has arisen. When switching transition to animation duration, the animation is slower at the beginning and end and faster in the middle. This causes the dots not to hit the "clock" correctly. I updated the question with your suggested change, so you can see the difference.

Comment: Search for CSS animation with **steps**, there should be a good SVG clock example with **steps** somewehere out there in Google country

Comment: I have already managed to understand the reason and correct it. Thank you for your help.